# computing a limit of a ratio of derangements

Tags: combinatorics, limits, permutations

Fix $m$. Consider $\lbrace 1,\ldots ,n\rbrace$. Let $a_1\dots a_n$ be a permutation of this set. How many permutations are there such that $a_i\not=i$ for all $i$ and each $i$ travels at most $m$ spots? small valued examples below.

Suppose $m=2$.

If $n=2$, the only permutation we like is 2,1.

If $n=3$, then the permutations we like are of the form $\_\, \_\,\_$ where 2 or 3 can go in slot 1; 1 or 3 can go in slot 2, and 2 or 3 can go in slot 3. This gives a total of 2 permutations. In this simplified setting we cannot resort to the fundamental counting principle due to the constraint-the number of times you can choose each number.
Is there a way to generalize this to the set of $n$ elements for any integer $m$?

**EDIT:** I am trying to compute -for a fixed $m$-the limit of the number of such permutations described above, denoted $D_{n,.m}$, divided by $D_n$  as $n\to \infty$. I  wonder if we can still estimate the ratio for large $n$.

Comment: Without restriction on the distance, these are known as the [derangement numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: Yes. The constraint throws me off. This idea of  assigning certain numbers to _ _ _ $\ldots$ has been my best but I don't know how to count them all in a convenient way.

Comment: Hmm. Could we look at these as a Frobenius complements to $\langle (12345\ldots n)\rangle$?

Comment: I don't know, I'll read up on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any fixed $m$, this limit is zero.  The number of allowed permutations is bounded above by $(2m)^n$, since each of the $n$ values has at most $2m$ final positions (the $m$ to the left and the $m$ to the right of its initial position).  So $D_{n,m}$ grows exponentially in $n$ (at most).  On the other hand, the total number of derangements is $!n \sim n!/e$, which grows superexponentially in $n$.